# install opencv-python using Python3 in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu

I wish to install opencv-python via the command in Ubuntu 15.04 machine

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

But as soon as I run this command I get the following error :

```
Downloading/unpacking opencv-python
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement opencv-python
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for opencv-python
Storing debug log for failure in /home/Nadeem/.pip/pip.log
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first upgrade pip using `sudo`.

```
arsho:~/workspace $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip                                                                                       
Successfully installed pip
```

Now install `opencv-python` again using `sudo` command.

```
arsho:~/workspace $ sudo pip3 install opencv-python
Successfully installed numpy-1.13.1 opencv-python-3.3.0.10
```

Finally check the `opencv-python` version and location information using pip.

```
arsho:~/workspace $ pip3 show opencv-python
---
Name: opencv-python
Version: 3.3.0.10
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Requires: numpy
```

I have tested this using `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` in https://c9.io/.

Answer (score 4):

You can install opencv from source.
Follow [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/) link to do so.
Or you may need to upgrade your pip3 using the following command

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

## EDIT

For completeness(and in case the link is broken) I've listed here steps to compile and install OpenCV from source on Ubuntu(Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with python 3).

### Step 1 Update the packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

### Step 2 Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git pkg-config # Developer tools required to compile opencv
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev libtiff4-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev # Libraries required to read various image format from disk
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev # Libraries required to read various video formats
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev # Required by opencv for GUI features
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran # Packages used by opencv to optimize various functions.

pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

### Step 3 setup virtual environment(using conda)

```
conda create -n opencv-exmaple-env python=3.6

source activate opencv-exmaple-env # Activate the envirnoment
```

### Step 4 Install packages required to compile opencv

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev # If the python version is not 3.6 then make changes to this command accordingly. 
pip install numpy # This should be done after the environment in Step 3 is activated
```

### Step 5: Build and install OpenCV 3.0 with Python 3.4+ bindings

#### 5.1 Clone the opencv source

```sh
cd ~
mkdir opencv-source
cd opencv-source
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 3.3.0 # Branch you want to compile from
```

#### 5.2 Clone Opencv Contrib rep

Contains exptra functionalities such as standard keypoint detectors and local invariant descriptors (such as SIFT, SURF, etc.)

```sh
cd ~
mkdir opencv-contrib
cd opencv-contrib
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git
cd opencv_contrib
git checkout 3.3.0 # The version you want to compile
```

#### 5.3 Compile,build and install

```sh
cd ~/opencv-source/opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv-contrib/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

#### 5.4 Link installed opencv object file to python site packages

```sh
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so /path-to-python-sitepackages-of-the-environment/cv2.so
```

### 6 Verify installation

```py
import cv2
```

If the above code runs without error then opencv is installed successfully.